# NDK build issue: aarch64-linux-android-ar.exe xxx.cpp.o: No such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, unix-ar

Background: I'm building a gradle project with linked C++ project (external native build).

In that procedure, an unexpected error happened:

> D:\jenkins_node\workspace\new_build_android2\new_android_build_test\android-ndk-r20\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\aarch64-linux-android-ar.exe: sandbox/3rd/Bullet/src/BulletCollision/CMakeFiles/BulletCollision.dir/CollisionDispatch/btActivatingCollisionAlgorithm.cpp.o: No such file or directory

Then I reproduced this error in command line on the same machine:

```
D:\jenkins_node\workspace\new_build_android2\new_android_build_test\engine\projects\android\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\arm64-v8a>D:\jenkins_node\workspace\new_build_android2\new_android_build_test\android-ndk-r20\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\aarch64-linux-android-ar.exe qc .\sandbox\3rd\Bullet\src\BulletCollision\libBulletCollision.a  @CMakeFiles/BulletCollision.rsp
```

The content of `@CMakeFiles/BulletCollision.rsp` is https://gist.github.com/zwcloud/4897dde48194e5324c899f17a3356be6 , which contains:

```
sandbox/3rd/Bullet/src/BulletCollision/CMakeFiles/BulletCollision.dir/CollisionDispatch/btActivatingCollisionAlgorithm.cpp.o
```

The file `btActivatingCollisionAlgorithm.cpp.o` does exist:

[image: file <code>btActivatingCollisionAlgorithm.cpp.o</code> does exist]

What's the possible reason why `aarch64-linux-android-ar.exe` reports the error that `btActivatingCollisionAlgorithm.cpp.o` doesn't exist? And how to fix this?

UPDATE:

I just tried

```
D:\jenkins_node\workspace\new_build_android2\new_android_build_test\android-ndk-r20\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\aarch64-linux-android-ar.exe qc sandbox\3rd\Bullet\src\BulletCollision\libBulletCollision.a sandbox/3rd/Bullet/src/BulletCollision/CMakeFiles/BulletCollision.dir/CollisionDispatch/btActivatingCollisionAlgorithm.cpp.o
```

And it still reported the same error:

> D:\jenkins_node\workspace\new_build_android2\new_android_build_test\android-ndk-r20\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\aarch64-linux-android-ar.exe: sandbox/3rd/Bullet/src/BulletCollision/CMakeFiles/BulletCollision.dir/CollisionDispatch/btActivatingCollisionAlgorithm.cpp.o: No such file or directory

Environment: Win10, CMake 3.10 (downloaded by Android Studio 3.5 in Settings -> SDK Tools), Android NDK r20

Comment: Any idea how to proceed solving this issue is appreciated! I'm not just looking for a working answer.

Comment: This is very likely caused by the 260 path length limit on windows. Even if I removed that limit in group policy, this issue still persisted. Maybe `aarch64-linux-android-ar.exe` uses some win32 API internally that is still using `MAX_PATH` [which is fixed to 260](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation).

Comment: "Maybe aarch64-linux-android-ar.exe uses some win32 API internally that is still using MAX_PATH which is fixed to 260." That's very likely.